# Using mongoose to find a document that matches one of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document with the `bankAccounts` attribute:

```
const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    bankAccounts: [
        {
            currency: String,
            personType: String,
            bankName: String,
            branchCode: String,
            accountNumber: String,
            bic: String,
            bankCity: String,
            accountType: String,
            isPrimary: Boolean,
        },
    ]
})
```

So a user can have many bank accounts. It can have `currency: USD` and a `currency: EUR` bank accounts.

I'm querying the users and retrieving one user with an array of currencies this user have, so in this example my array would be `['USD', 'EUR']`.

I need to make a new query, to a new collection, searching all orders that match one of the currencies in the array:

```
const orders = await Orders.find({status: "Allocating", currency: oneOfTheArray })
```

How can I achieve an `OR` condition on my query, iterating all currencies in my array?

Thank you in advance

Comment: i'm still not clear but is it like you want to retrieve all orders that have currency either USD or EUR if yes then you can modify above query like const orders = await Orders.find({status: "Allocating", currency: {$in:oneOfTheArray} })

Comment: @harshitkohli yes you're correct. Thank you for your reply. If you want the accepted answer badge, please turn your comment into an answer. Thanks

Comment: yeah i would appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const orders = await Orders.find({status: "Allocating", currency: {$in:oneOfTheArray} })
```